# Removing apcsystray entry from notification area after Uninstall?

Tags: windows-7, ups, apc-powerchute

I ran into some problems with APC's UPS software, so I uninstalled it from my Windows 7 32-bit system. However, a reference to the `apcsystray` app is still showing up in the taskbar notification configuration page.

It's not a big deal, but since I cleaned everything having to do with apc out of the registry I'm curious why the reference is still there. Is there a way to look up what executable is associated with a notification area icon?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
 Start>run
type msconfig
go to the startup tab and then click "show all publishers/vendors"
look for a startup app from "apc" and disable it from starting.

That should also show you the path of the exe.